# Python Executing SQL fails over due to non existing field in json data

Tags: python, sql, json, django

I am getting some JSON data from a third party API. I am trying to add that data into my own database to be used for a website. I loop through each record in the JSON and execute a SQL query to insert that data into my database. However some records in the JSON data doesn't exist, and therefore causes my query to fail. I have set defaults for these fields for this reason however it still falls over.

`isNonFoilOnly` field will only appear in some of of the records in the JSON data.

**models.py**

```py
class Set(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    keyrune_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    base_set_size = models.IntegerField()
    total_set_size = models.IntegerField()
    is_online_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_non_foil_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_foil_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```py
    response = requests.request("GET", "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/SetList.json")
    data = response.json()["data"]
    sorted_obj = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['releaseDate'], reverse=False)
    sql = """
        INSERT INTO dashboard_set
          (code, keyrune_code, name, type, release_date, base_set_size, total_set_size, is_online_only, is_non_foil_only, is_foil_only, sale_status)
        VALUES
          ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )
        ON CONFLICT (code) DO UPDATE 
            SET keyrune_code = %s,
                name = %s,
                type = %s,
                release_date = %s,
                base_set_size = %s,
                total_set_size = %s,
                is_online_only = %s,
                is_non_foil_only = %s,
                is_foil_only = %s;
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        for entry in sorted_obj:
            cur.execute(sql, (
                entry["code"],
                entry["keyruneCode"],
                entry["name"],
                entry["type"],
                entry["releaseDate"],
                entry["baseSetSize"],
                entry["totalSetSize"],
                entry["isOnlineOnly"],
                entry["isNonFoilOnly"],
                entry["isFoilOnly"],
                False,
                entry["keyruneCode"],
                entry["name"],
                entry["type"],
                entry["releaseDate"],
                entry["baseSetSize"],
                entry["totalSetSize"],
                entry["isOnlineOnly"],
                entry["isNonFoilOnly"],
                entry["isFoilOnly"]
            ))
            conn.commit()
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    return redirect('dashboard:sets')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a SQL problem, but just a python error. `entry["isNonFoilOnly"]` will fail with a key error if `isNonFoilOnly` is not in the dict. You can use `entry.get('isNonFoilOnly')` instead, which will return `None` if the key is not present.

Comment: hello, that works to an extent. I get a nullable error because I haven't set the field to nullable. But I want it to default to false, which is doesn't seem want to work.

Comment: You can pass a second parameter `entry.get(‘isNonFoilOnly’, False)`. That would actually pass False, but not trigger the sql default.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You seem to using Django and not using it at the same time. The Django way to do this is:

```py
from yourapp.models import Set

def yourview(request):
    response = requests.request("GET", "https://mtgjson.com/api/v5/SetList.json")
    data = response.json()["data"]
    # Not caring about sort, because why?
    for entry in data:
        code = data.pop('code', None)
        if not code:
            continue  # or raise
        Set.objects.update_or_create(code=code, defaults=data)

    return redirect('dashboard:sets')
```